# Working with Interpolating Functions

Tags: interpolation

I have two sets of data that are not regularly sampled, and I want to produce a quantitative measurement of how similar they are while fitting them with an $x$ shift and $x$ and $y$ scaling.

Following the *Mathematica* interpolation documentation, `f = Interpolation[data]` gives me nice graphs and allows me to access one interpolated point at a time via `f[x]`.

What I'd like to do is something along the lines of:

```
experiment = Interpolation[expdata]    
FindFit[theorydata, a*experiment[b*x + c], {a, b, c}, x]
```

where `theorydata` and `expdata` are non-regularly sampled lists of $x$ and $y$ values.

This successfully inputs $x$ values from the `theorydata` list, but just prints them out as `FindFit[{theorydata}, {a InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.32878}}, <>][0.499755 b + c] ...]`

---

Alternatively, if something like that is not an option, it would be useful to know how to generally work with interpolating functions. For example, I cannot seem to subtract two interpolating functions from each other:

```
experiment = Interpolation[expdata]
theory = Interpolation[theorydata]
f = experiment - theory
```

This outputs:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.32758}}, <>] - InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.32878}}, <>]
```

and, `f[0.1]`, for example outputs:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.32758}}, <>] - InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.32878}}, <>][0.1]
```

I am, however, able to re-sample the interpolated data with:

```
result = Table[{x, experiment[x]}, {x, 0, 0.3, 0.01}]
```

This then gives me a regularly sampled list.

---

In summary, I suppose the biggest question here is how to work with `InterpolatingFunction` objects. Can they be added/subtracted? Can they be treated as a function and used in fitting algorithms? How exactly is an `InterpolatingFunction` stored in *Mathematica*?

**EDIT:** Fixed a typo in the output

Sample of data (small sample of a large number of points):

```
    expdata={{0, 0.032174}, {0.00497, 0.032446}, {0.010701, 0.032923}, {0.015671, 
  0.033402}, {0.021403, 0.034199}, {0.028477, 0.035362}, {0.033447, 
  0.036444}, {0.039179, 0.038074}, {0.044149, 0.039642}, {0.049119, 
  0.041422}}
    theorydata={{0, 0.033955}, {0.00497, 0.034502}, {0.010701, 0.035312}, {0.015671, 
  0.036135}, {0.020641, 0.037109}, {0.026373, 0.038481}, {0.031343, 
  0.039824}, {0.036313, 0.041344}, {0.041283, 0.043037}, {0.047014, 
  0.045256}}
```

Note that that the datasets are very similar, but they are not sampled for all of the same x values.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your two datasets? Also, your idea of fitting might not be along the lines of what `FindFit` does, i.e. you need to have an analytical model and experimental data points. In your case, you could generate a function that expresses the squared differences between your experimental and corresponding theoretical data points as a function of the shift parameters, and then minimize that function numerically to get the best-fit shift parameters for this the theoretical calculations fit the experimental findings.

Comment: @MarcoB You're partially right,but remember that _"I have two sets of data that are not regularly sampled,"_ So probably no correspondence

Comment: @MarcoB I added the first 10 datapoints for the theory and experimental datasets. Since I can use the Table function to resample the interpolated data, I could do a manual sum of squares minimization loop, altering the shift/scaling of the original datasets with each iteration. I would really like to avoid having to to that though.

Comment: @belisarius That's an excellent point: I had overlooked that complicating factor. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Snipatomic Thank you for posting the data; please take a look at my answer below. I hope it is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let us use your theoretical and experimental data points to generate interpolating functions:

```
(* Calculate interpolating functions for the two datasets *)
expint = Interpolation[expdata];
theorint = Interpolation[theorydata];
```

Now we use the interpolating functions to "resample" your data points; we can then express the point-by-point squared differences between the two data sets as a function of stretch and offset parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$.

```
(* Generate sum of squared distances as function of a, b, c to be minimized *)
Clear[diff]
diff[a_, b_, c_] = Total[Table[(a expint[b x + c] - theorint[x])^2, {x, 0, 0.047, 0.005}]];
```

---

We can minimize the squared difference function `diff` numerically to find the values of the parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$ that make `expdata` best approximate `theorydata`:

```
(* Find a, b, c that minimize diff *)
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
paramsatminimum = NMinimize[diff[a, b, c], {a, b, c}][[2]]
On[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
```

During minimization `NMinimize` tries out some values of the parameters that bring the argument of the interpolating functions outside of their domain, which forces extrapolation, and a lot of warnings are generated. Since no harm is done by those attempts, I temporarily turn `Off` the warning message, carry out the optimization, then turn it back `On`.

---

Finally, we can plot the results by plugging the best-fit values of the parameters into the interpolating function `expint`, and compare them with the `theorydata` points:

```
(* Plot resulting interpolating function together with theorydata points *)
Plot[
  a expint[b x + c] /. paramsatminimum, {x, 0, 0.05},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point@theorydata},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
]

(* Out: {a -> 1.01519, b -> 0.861444, c -> 0.0159744} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am having one problem currently: even when I run your code as written, I end up with a result that is wildly off. However, if I set the `WorkingPrecision->10` in the `NMinimize` loop, I end up with accurate results. Is there a default setting that is messed up here?

Comment: @Snipatomic When you say that you run the code as written, are you using the small sample data set, or your complete set? What version of MMA do you run? I am on MMA 10.2, Win7-64. I ran my calculations without specifying any particular precision value, so they ran at machine precision; you shouldn't need to set anything either. Do you get any errors/warnings?

Comment: I am running 10.2, Win10-64, Student Edition. My comment originally applied to the small dataset - it spat out `{a -> 0.88840, b -> 0.61518, c -> 0.03802}`, which is quite different from what you posted. However, with `WorkingPrecision->10`, I get exactly what you wrote. The only errors in the output are dmval (when I allow the warnings that you turned off).

I have played with it a bit more now (both with the small dataset and my full set), and the `NMinimize` function seems to be extremely sensitive to the `WorkingPrecision` setting. Is there another way I can make this more robust?